# Photoshop - retrieve graphic from off screen / outside canvas

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I've got some text somewhere outside of the canvas border but I can't find it.  Usually using `move` tool I can squiggle around until it peeks onto the canvas, but this time it must be WAY outside.

I've hacked my way around the problem with copy and paste, but is there a "correct" way to pull it back onto the canvas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Highlight the Layer in the Layers Panel.

Choose `Edit > Free Transform`.

Now `Choose View > Fit on Screen`.

You will be zoomed out until the free transform handles are showing.. that is where the text is located.

It's faster if you use shortcuts. On the Mac... Highlight text layer, <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>, <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>. (That's a zero)

Comment: This is the way I do it, too. Definitely works and is quick. +1

Answer (score 4):

If you select the layer where the text is located, simply align the layer vertically and horizontally. The text should now be in the center of your document.

Comment: I don't know why I did this really, I mean it is not like this problem should occur a lot and it is not super difficult to get around, but here's an action that (pretty much does what Johannes is saying) fetches an object to the center or top left corner https://www.dropbox.com/s/maeve9w6lh8aapj/Fetch_Object.atn Just select layer(s) and run one of the actions.

Comment: I know why you did it: because it's fun. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go under Image menu > select "Reveal all"

Comment: Note: this **will** change the canvas size to fit the unseen content within it, rather than simply showing where the off-canvas item is located.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness:  **View**  >  **Show**  >  **All**

Your missing layer will appear as a blue rectangle wherever it is. (You may have to back way out to see it). Drag it back onto the canvas.

**View**  >  **Show**  >  **None** to get rid of the grid that gets imposed on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Bjango has a [Photoshop action](http://bjango.com/articles/actions/) called "Center of Canvas" which automatically moves whatever is on the presently selected layer to the center of the canvas.